# In app purchase Buy product working on 1 view but not the other

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Ive got an IOS app where In app purchases have been set up. I have 2 different views with the same code. One is being called normally through the storyboard, another is being called as a Modal Segue

The one being called as a Segue CONSISTENTLY crashes on this line of code:

```
 SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyAdButton.tag];
```

**in the context of:**

```
- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyAdButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyAdButton.tag];

    //    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}
```

I have no idea why this is happening. The code on both views is IDENTICAL but the only difference I know is that one opens via a Segue and the other doesn't. Could this be strangely causing an issue?

I can provide any other info if it helps

Comment: what is crash report ?

Comment: Unidentified selector sent to instance